# Why won't this std::chrono::year_month_day_last code compile?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I am trying to use this ChatGPT code to get the last day of this month:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto ymd = std::chrono::year_month_day{ std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::months>(now) };
auto last_day = std::chrono::year_month_day_last{ ymd.year(), ymd.month() };
```

But this will not compile:

> error C2440: '': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::chrono::year_month_day'

There are other messages too. I am compiling for C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`year_month_day`'s constructor accepts `sys_days` which cannot be implicitly constructed from `months` because the former is not divisible by `days`.

The second parameter of `year_month_day_last`'s constructor is `month_day_last` instead of `month`, so you must explicitly construct a `month_day_last` object.

This should work

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto ymd = std::chrono::year_month_day{ std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now) };
auto last_day = std::chrono::year_month_day_last{ ymd.year(), ymd.month()/std::chrono::last };
```

Comment: Upvoted.  Here's a more concise syntax to create `last_day`:  `auto last_day = ymd.year()/ymd.month()/std::chrono::last;`